# Xamarin Forms In app billing for Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, in-app-billing

I'm making an app where I have to have in app purchases (buying keys that I can further use in the app).

I have looked at this component http://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.inappbilling, but I have no idea how I can implement this in xamarin *forms*. Is there anyone out there willing to help me with this problem? Is there any open source projects with in app purchase that I can look at?

Answer (score 1):

I know its late, but this might help someone:

The way to do achieve this is to create a service and then surface it to a standard interface (as per your requirement) that will be consumed within the forms project.

You can even use MessagingCenter to communicate between Android and Xamarin.Forms project.

```
FormsPrject:
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, string>(this, "BuyProduct", "buyButtonPressed");

AndroidPoject
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage, string>(this, "BuyProduct", (sender, arg) =>
{
    //logic to buy product
}
```

Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 1):

The question is very vague so I will offer a general answer and some notes that I found important.  I am using Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin Forms 2.3.0.107.

I would use abstraction for this instead of sending messages directly between the projects.

The basic idea is, you will create a public interface in your Xamarin Forms project.  Since your Andriod project has a reference to the Xamarin Forms project, it can use this public interface.  Then you will implement this interface in your Android project will all of the billing logic.  In the Xamarin Forms project.  Using the Dependency service we can get the existing instance of the implementation into the Xamarin Forms project.  Then, you can code against the interface.  This is especially useful if you ever want to do an iPhone or other implementation, because you would never need to make changes to the Xamarin Forms code; you can just plug in new implementations.

- It might be a bit out of scope but, be sure to [meet all of the Google requirements](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-test) as far as setting up your developer account and your merchant account and your API account.  It is all very confusing and messy.
- The Xamarin component in nuget is currently version 1.5.  However, the component has a newer published version.  You want to use the newer (2.0 or higher) version.
- Use the Android SDK manager to install the *Google Play Billing Library*.
- In your Android project, add a reference to Xamarin.InAppBilling and add a Xamarin.InAppBilling component.
- The Google object has to live in an Android activity, because you depend on overriding an activity method to complete purchases (I used the MainActivity here and made the google object a static for easy access)
- Testing this with Google Play is a hassle.  The documentation is confusing because of differences between versions.  You cannot use actual product id's until you publish your app.  They provide test id's that can be used during testing but they only offer some functionality.

I have made these code examples as minimal as possible to illustrate the concept.  You will obviously want to do much more.

**Xamarin Forms project**

Create an interface:

```
public interface IInAppBilling
{
    void Pay(string productId);
}
```

Any time you want to use the billing service, you use `IInAppBilling billingService = DependencyService.Get<IInAppBilling>();` to get a reference to the device-specific (Android) implementation.

```
//call this from a button click or whatever
void BuySomething(string somethingId)
{
    //Get any IInAppBilling object that is registered with the DependencyService.
    IInAppBilling billingService = DependencyService.Get<IInAppBilling>();
    billingService.Pay(somethingId);
}
```

**Android Project**

Override an activity's OnCreate method and create an InAppBillingServiceConnection:

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
    public static InAppBillingServiceConnection google;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        google = new InAppBillingServiceConnection(this, "MII...ApplicationKey");
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```

Create a class that implements the Xamarin Forms interface we created earlier.  It is important not to ignore the `assembly: Dependency`annotation at the top.  This is what makes the class available to the Dependency service in the Xamarin Forms object:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(com.myapp.InAppBilling))]
namespace com.myapp
{
    class InAppBilling :IInAppBilling
    {
        public void Pay(string productId)
        {
             MainActivity.google.BillingHandler.BuyProduct(productId, ItemType.Product, "MyUniquePayload");
        }
    }
}
```

Override the activity's OnActivityResult method to finalize purchases:

```
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Ask the open service connection's billing handler to process this request
        try
        {
            google.BillingHandler.HandleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log it or something?
        }

    }
```